Constant speed (at terminal velocity) and zero $g$
I have read the question What would a person experience in a free-falling elevator in a shaft long enough to reach terminal velocity? here and the answer was that you feel exactly the same if the elevator is at rest or is moving at a constant speed (at terminal velocity).
But there is one thing I can't get my head around. What if we replace the elevator with the ISS?
Both are falling at constant speed but there is zero $g$ at the ISS.
What makes the ISS different to the elevator falling terminal velocity?

Terminal velocity at zero $g$ is zero ms$^{-1}$.

Terminal velocity means that the friction force $F_f$, that acts in the opposite direction of the velocity cancels out any further acceleration. For a free falling object that means $F_g + F_f = 0 $, so the net force acting on the free-falling elevator is $0$. However, the netforce on the ISS is $F_g$.
While it's true that the ISS is moving at constant speed, the velocity is not constant. Note that speed is a scalar quantity $|\vec{v}|$, but velocity also has a direction, and that is constantly changing.

It may help to think of it with equations. What happens to your position and the position of the elevator whenever you a small distance above the floor.
Elevator is at terminal velocity $v_T$
In this case the elevator will move at a constant velocity but you will be accelerated by gravity. If you start a distance $h$  above the floor and you are already moving at the same speed as the elevator then the two position equations will be
$$x_{\text{elev.}} = -v_T t$$
$$x_{\text{you}} = h -v_T t -\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
That means the distance between you and the elevator will be
$$x_{\text{you}} - x_{\text{elev.}} = h - \frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
That's exactly the same equation as if the elevator were staying at rest on the ground.
Elevator is in free-fall
In this case the elevator does not have a constant speed. It accelerates downward at the same rate as you, $g$.
$$x_{\text{elev.}} = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
$$x_{\text{you}} = h  -\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
$$x_{\text{you}} - x_{\text{elev.}} = h$$
That means you won't get any closer to or further from the elevator floor. It's exactly like there is no gravity at all.

The only force on the ISS is gravity. The total acceleration of the ISS is slightly less than $9.8$ m/s$^2$. (The ISS is farther from the center of the earth than the surface is.) This is the centripetal acceleration needed to deflect its trajectory from a straight line into a circle.
The total acceleration of a person at the start of free fall is $9.8$ m/s$^2$. The sensations are the same.

At terminal velocity, the two forces are gravity and air resistance. You know the two forces add to $0$ because the total acceleration is $0$.
The two forces on a person standing on the ground are gravity and the reaction of the ground pushing him upward. The total acceleration is $0$.
In both cases, the sensation of weight does not come from gravity. It comes from the forces pushing on the bottom surface of the person. This accelerates the bottom surface. The person would deform if he didn't generate internal forces to keep himself rigid.

The total force on a person floating is space far from Earth is $0$. The sensation is the same as in the ISS or the start of free fall.
Gravity pulls on every atom and accelerates each one equally. The person experiences no deformation. He doesn't need to generate internal forces to keep himself rigid.
